# Serializing very small numbers stored in JavaScriptObject

Tags: gwt

I have a 2D array of doubles that I am representing in GWT as an object of type `JsArray<JsArrayNumber>`. If I were to convert the array to Javascript, it would look something like this:

```
var test = [[0.6578396255487482,7.875995798E-314,3.1688557021480858E55],
                [9.365832954E-315,0.9866897170404328,9.378991533366766E54],
            [4.999803162025956E51,6.32672779777942E54,1.987536773023561]];
```

The problem is that when I try to serialize the GWT object to a JSON string by using `JSONObject.toString()`, the process hangs up and never finishes. Through some messing around, I figured out that if I change the very small numbers (the ones ending in E-315) to zero that the serialization completes successfully. Why does GWT have a hard time with these numbers? Is `JSONObject.toString()` the correct method for serializing something like this? I realize that since these numbers are so small, I could sanitize these objects before serialization, but I would prefer not to alter them if possible since they are the results of a somewhat sensitive calculation.

EDIT:

Here is a sample unit test that shows the behavior:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArray;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArrayNumber;
import com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject;
import com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase;

public class SmallDoubleTest extends GWTTestCase{

    @Test
    public void test(){

        // When the very small numbers are replaced with 0 everything works
        String jsonStr = "[[0.6578396255487482,0,3.1688557021480858E55]," +
                        "[0,0.9866897170404328,9.378991533366766E54]," +
                        "[4.999803162025956E51,6.32672779777942E54,1.987536773023561]]";
        JsArray<JsArrayNumber> jsobj = buildArray(jsonStr);
        System.out.println("First Item: " + jsobj.get(0).get(0));
        System.out.println("Last Item: " + jsobj.get(2).get(2));
        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(jsobj);
        System.out.println(jsonobj.toString());

        // Putting them back in cause everything to hang on jsonobj.toString();
        jsonStr = "[[0.6578396255487482,7.875995798E-314,3.1688557021480858E55]," +
                         "[9.365832954E-315,0.9866897170404328,9.378991533366766E54]," +
                         "[4.999803162025956E51,6.32672779777942E54,1.987536773023561]]";
        jsobj = buildArray(jsonStr);
        System.out.println("First Item: " + jsobj.get(0).get(0));
        System.out.println("Last Item: " + jsobj.get(2).get(2));
        jsonobj = new JSONObject(jsobj);
        System.out.println(jsonobj.toString());
    }

    public static native JsArray<JsArrayNumber> buildArray(String json) /*-{
        return eval('(' + json + ')');
    }-*/;


    public String getModuleName(){
        return "com.iai.cgs.rest.gwtclient.CGSGWTClient";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is quite an interesting problem, can you provide some sample code which demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Your code works without any problems. I've tried one with GWT 2.5 @ Chrome 23 @ Mac OS , running as unit test, DevMode and compiled mode. Looks like the problem is caused by environment configuration, most likely DevMode plugin. Try to switch browser, update devmode plugin, or try to use latest GWT, or at least report versions of GWT, browser an operating system you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might suggest that the problem is with `JSONObject` implementation, since it always tries manually create json from supplied data. I'm pretty sure that using native browser `JSON.stringify()` function will be much faster. Example:

```
public static native String stringify(JavaScriptObject object)/*-{
   return JSON.stringify(object);
}-*/;
```

The only problem is that [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/json) (like IE6-7) do not support this function

Comment: JSON.stringify will still block forever when I pass in the string I used. By switching to using it, however, I was able to use the JSON.stringify(object, filter) method to easily sanitize my objects before serialization.

Answer (score 0):

As the JavaDoc of JSONArray already warn, the toString() may take a long time if the array is large (Although you might nog use JSONArray, toString may be expensive for JSON objects. If you have a JsArray, you could try the `join` method that also returns a String and is just native JavaScript and might be faster.

Comment: JsArray.join() displays the same behavior that JSONObj.toString() does. It just hangs forever.

Answer (score 0):

For a `JsArray` you have to use `new JSONArray(jsobj).toString()`, not `JSONObject`.